# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

These days I'm developing an angular-CLI project. Yesterday when I tried to make a new module in there, the terminal gave an error saying

> `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')`
> (only this error there wasn't any other explanations)

Then I found in the same way angular doesn't allow to make new components and give the same error. But there isn't any problem with the `ng serve` command. It works properly.

It would be a great help if you help me to solve this problem. I'll include some files. But if you want more details please mention them as comments because I can't understand where is the problem. Thanks in advance

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "chess-cabin-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "ns run android --no-hmr",
    "ios": "ns run ios --no-hmr",
    "mobile": "ns run",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.4",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^6.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.5.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "admin-lte": "^3.1.0-rc",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "emojionearea": "^3.4.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionicons": "^5.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^11.2.0",
    "@nativescript/tslint-rules": "~0.0.5",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^6.1.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "main": "main.tns.js"
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Chess-Cabin-Front": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Chess-Cabin-Front",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "webpack.config.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)",
              "admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js",
              "admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Chess-Cabin-Front:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Chess-Cabin-Front:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Chess-Cabin-Front:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Chess-Cabin-Front:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Chess-Cabin-Front:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Chess-Cabin-Front",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nativescript/schematics"
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply cancel the current console and run 'ng serve' again.

Comment: @RavinderKumar no it didn't work

Answer (score 21):

I've stumbled upon the same issue (with Angular v15.1.0 and TS v4.8.3), upgrading typescript to v4.9.4 solved for me!

Comment: Just noting, I first tried updating typescript to @latest but that installed version 5.something which threw a different error. typescript@4.9.4 or typescript@4.9.5 both worked

Answer (score 6):

I was having this same issue, in my case I was using animations in my own components, so the Brower animations module was already included.

The answer is in [this forum](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/25246#issuecomment-1223092868), I just added @angular/material without including the animations module [image: see screenshot].

Answer (score 1):

For me the following steps worked:

1. delete folder `node_modules`
2. delete file `package-lock.json`
3. run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

This error it's due because some dependency lack on your work directory.
To solve it, you should clean and rebuild your dependency.
follow this step:
step 1 delete your node_modules folder

1. $ rm -rf node_modules

or on Windows:
$ rmdir /s node_modules

step 2 clean cash

2. npm cache clean --force

step 3 install new node_module folde

3. npm install

Fore more information [check here](https://poe.com/s/vfOCTm7luLRhpcDX5crT)

Answer (score 0):

well, I suggest you to run `git diff` between the branches to check what changed in your project. in my case it was just the version of `@angular-devkit/core": "16.2.8"`. So I downgraded to `"@angular-devkit/core": "16.2.0"` and it works